# Is it Possible to Disable all controls including validators inside a div?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am wondering Is it Possible to disable all controls including validators inside a `div` using code behind in C#, like we do in jQuery.

The code I tried is

```
var controls = articlePickupDateTime.Controls.GetEnumerator();
while (controls.MoveNext())
{
    var item = controls.Current;
}
```

This was returning everything inside `div` including `span`, etc.

Comment: _Is it Possible_ Have you tried it?

Comment: yes I tried and Not able to do so I want to clarify is it possible or do i need to learn more

Comment: put your code which you have tried in your question.

Comment: I was trying to get controls usingControls.GetEnumerator() and traverse through one by one but failed to do so.

Comment: @SaurabhSharma put that code in your queston.

Answer (score 0):

```
RequiredFieldValidator1.Enabled = false;
```

'RequiredFieldValidator1' the id of validator control.

Answer (score 0):

Put all your controls in Panel Control and set

```
YourPanel.Enabled = false;
```